# Column Wise Operators Usage

Tags: support

I have been looking for a latex feature which can show operations in a columnwise fashion.
For example:-

If I would want to show $19 * 5$ to a $1$st grader, I would love to show it like this :-

$1 9$

x  $5$

__

$9 5$

Now obviously this isn't latexed and it looks ugly like this. I have searched for this feature in [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but I couldn't find it.

So is there a way to express this multiplication, or any operation in a column wise way?

I would appreciate if someone could tell me a way which also takes letters instead of numbers. I would be able to use them in cryptarithmetic puzzles.

Comment: There is a tex.stackexchange

Comment: @GerryMyerson Could u send the link for the page?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GerryMyerson I meant do you have the question or the answer which discusses the feature I am looking for?

Comment: What comes to mind is the `array` environment in MathJax.

Comment: And I meant that there is a website where questions about TeX and LaTeX are not off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pain, but it can be done using the `array` environment.
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1087946/25554 has an example:

$$\require{enclose}\begin{array}{rlll}
& \ \ \ \,0.1\\
17&\enclose{longdiv}{3.000\ldots} \\
& \ \ 1.7 \\ \hline
& \ \ 1\ 3
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{rlll}
& \ \ \ \,0.17\\
17&\enclose{longdiv}{3.000\ldots} \\
& \ \ 1.7 \\ \hline
& \ \ 1\ 30  \\
& \ \ 1\ 19 \\ \hline
& \ \ \ \ \ 11
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you, the second answer gives the way to include the symbol.

Answer (score 2):

$
\begin{array}{rr}
& 19 \\
\times &5 \\
\hline
&95
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I needed.